# Creating Multiple Multi-Band Images in Python

Tags: python-imaging-library

I am trying to create multiple multi-band images based off of Landsat data in Python. I am using PIL for this. How do I use PIL to create multiple multi-band images at the same time?

Here is the code:

```
import glob
from PIL import Image

year = 1999
band5_list = glob.glob('LE07_L1TP_037032_*_01_T1_B5.TIF')
band4_list = glob.glob('LE07_L1TP_037032_*_01_T1_B4.TIF')
band3_list = glob.glob('LE07_L1TP_037032_*_01_T1_B3.TIF')

for band5 in band5_list:
    for band4 in band4_list:
        for band3 in band3_list: 
            Band_5 = Image.open(band5).convert('L')
            Band_4 = Image.open(band4).convert('L')
            Band_3 = Image.open(band3).convert('L')
            try:
                Veg_Image = Image.merge('RGB', (Band_5, Band_4, Band_3))
            except ValueError:
                print('Impossible to merge. Try again.')
                break
            year += 1
            Veg_Image.save('Landsat_' + str(year) + '.tif')
```

Comment: Please also avoid `try: except:` clauses in code you post (you can use them in your own code obviously) so that any errors don't get hidden. Then can you edit your question and add more details about any errors (complete traceback formatted as code using the {} button) or unexpected outputs. Thanks!

Comment: Can I also suggest you consider using [`rasterio`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) instead of PIL. `rasterio` is designed for georeferenced raster imagery, unlike PIL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your nested loops will cause issues, as for each element in `Band5_list` you will loop through *all* elements in `Band4_list` and for each element in `Band4_list` you'll loop through all elements in `Band3_list`.

So assuming you have 3 lists with 5 bands each, `Band5_list` gets looped through once, `Band4_list` five times and `Band3_list` 25 times.

Instead, try using the [`zip()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
for band5, band4, band3 in zip(Band5_list, Band4_list, Band3_list):
    Band_5 = Image.open(band5).convert('L')
    Band_4 = Image.open(band4).convert('L')
    Band_3 = Image.open(band3).convert('L')
    etc...
```

Comment: Thanks. By the way, does the order of the bands in Image.merge matter?

Comment: By the way, can you also tell me how to do it in rasterio? I know that you mentioned that that works with georeferenced imagery.

Comment: Start by looking at the documentation https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=Merge There's a command line tool and a python API.

Comment: I have. I am using the Python API, not the command line tool.

Comment: Then ask a new question